# Error: Cannot find module '@nx/nx-linux-x64-gnu'

Tags: typescript, npm, github-actions, npm-install, nrwl-nx

I'm trying to run the build of my Angular project using [NX](https://nx.dev/) in the CI with GitHub Actions, but it fails with errors such as:

> npm ERR! code 1 npm ERR! path /runner/_work/myapp/node_modules/nx npm
> ERR! command failed npm ERR! command sh -c node ./bin/post-install npm
> ERR! /runner/_womyapp/node_modules/nx/src/native/index.js:244 npm ERR!
> throw loadError npm ERR!     ^ npm ERR!  npm ERR! Error: Cannot find
> module '@nx/nx-linux-x64-gnu'

> NX   Missing Platform Dependency
>
> The Nx CLI could not find or load the native binary for your
> supported platform (linux-x64).    This likely means that optional
> dependencies were not installed correctly, or your system is missing
> some system dependencies.    For more information please see
> https://nx.dev/recipes/troubleshooting/troubleshoot-nx-install-issues
>
> Error: Process completed with exit code 1.

Answer (score 3):

There are several suggested solutions on GitHub for this issues, for example deleting `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` and regenerating them with `npm install`, however none of such solutions worked for me.

I finally found the [solution pointed out by the user k3nsei](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/17767#issuecomment-1630543307) which worked for me:

1. Add the following to your `package.json` file (replace the `18.0.4` nx version with the one you are using, preferably the latest one):

```
  "optionalDependencies": {
    "@nx/nx-darwin-arm64": "18.0.4",
    "@nx/nx-darwin-x64": "18.0.4",
    "@nx/nx-linux-x64-gnu": "18.0.4",
    "@nx/nx-win32-x64-msvc": "18.0.4"
  },
```

2. In your CI scripts, run the `npm ci` or `npm install` with  `--include=optional`, example:

```
- name: Install dependencies
  run: npm ci --include=optional
```